# ASP.NET 5 Dependency Resolution

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to tinker arround with ASP.NET5 and all the new Magic we get.
I created a small Application, which receives a MAC-Address and sends a WakeOnLan-Package. For the abstraction of the WoL, I tried to use the SharpPCap-Library: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12458/SharpPcap-A-Packet-Capture-Framework-for-NET

I can add the References and even set the Object, but it seems only be avaliable on 4.5. Simply put, do need Asemblies be compatible to DNX 4.5.1 AND DNX Core 5.0?

I tried to add the Automapper, which works, but this one is shown on both Reference-Folders DNX 4.5.1 and 5.0. Does this mean, this Assembly is kindahow working on both Versions? If yes so, how is this possible, if other Assemblies don't seem to be compatible?

My 3. question raises from the Project-References: I added the Model-Project to my WebGui one, but Intellisense keeps marking the Model-Objects red and telling me, he can't resolve it. Funnily enough, building and Runtime work perfectly fine. Is this an issue of the Compiler atm?

If you have any resources on the general topic, I would be glad as well. I found some threads about this theme, like Jon Skeets problem: [How can I diagnose missing dependencies (or other loader failures) in dnx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007962/how-can-i-diagnose-missing-dependencies-or-other-loader-failures-in-dnx) or the diagnosing: http://davidfowl.com/diagnosing-dependency-issues-with-asp-net-5/ but I guess, my problem is on a more basic level.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need DNX Core 5.0 - that's all the .NET Core stuff which SharpPCap probably isn't compatible with.  If you can, just get rid of that framework like this in your `project.json` file:

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
    }
  },
```

It's probably the same thing for your Model-Project.  getting rid of dnxcore50 should help.  Basically by doing that you are saying your project needs full .NET, so it might not be as easy to run it on Linux etc...

Comment: Can you tell me what it means, if a Reference shows up on both Frameworks and how this is possible? Thanks anyway, if it works this is for sure thr answer.

Answer (score 1):

The red line issue might be a re-sharper problem if you're running that?

see: [Dnx 4.5.1/Dnx Core 5.0 Ambiguous reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877165/dnx-4-5-1-dnx-core-5-0-ambiguous-reference/34049577#34049577)